# Are Slippers of Spider Climb usable while Wild Shaped?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, druid, wild-shape

Are [Slippers of Spider Climb](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/r-z/slippers-of-spider-climbing) usable while Wild Shaped?

I don't know if the item is use-activated is the problem.  I'm under the impression that use activated items, like Boots of Striding and Springing are, and would work for my Druid.

Answer (score 2):

**If you take it off, and then put it on again, yes.  Otherwise, no.**

If it's an item your new form can wear, about which the rules are generally pretty forgiving (a dolphin has two ring slots), take it off, change shape, then put it back on again.  Is this against the spirit of the rules?  Maybe.  But it's also kinda meh.  I doubt anyone's going to kick up a fuss about you being a bear wearing a hat, or awkwardly, a pair of slippers.

Answer (score 1):

### No.

That information can be found in the sidebar [here](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/polymorph)

> The pathfinder version of Polymorph rules states: Unless the new form is humanoid, all gear merges into the form.  Constant bonuses (except AC) remain.  Activation items can't be activated. Material components are not accessible while merged into the form.

Wild shape functions as a Beast Shape I spell, which puts it into the Polymorph spell category and makes it subject to the polymorph rules present in the Pathfinder campaign setting, which are present above.

What this means is that the equipment will fuse with you when you polymorph using Wild shape and become inert until your Wild shape ends. After all, why would you need Slippers of Spider Climb when you can polymorph into a giant spider to accomplish the same result?

Comment: Where was it carried over?  I was under the impression that: *“Wildshape functions as Beast Shape, Elemental Body, or Plant shape unless otherwise noted.”* Nothing concerning gear is mentioned, so the polymorph rules apply.

Comment: I've added the page of the OGL that specifies that the rules were the same to the answer.

Comment: While this is true, without an explanation as to why a sidebar for the *polymorph* spell has any bearing on Wild Shape, this answer is very much incomplete.

Comment: Wild shape functions as a Beast Shape I spell, which puts it into the polymorph spell category and makes it subject to the polymorph rules present in the pathfinder campaign setting.

Answer (score 0):

#### No.

Wild shape functions like either [*beast shape*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/beast-shape), [*elemental body*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/elemental-body) or [*plant shape*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/plant-shape-i). All of these are [transmutation (polymorph)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Transmutation-Polymorph) spells, which means they are subject to the general rules outlined for the polymorph subschool, unless they specifically say otherwise (such as is the case for abilities of your new form you gain).

> When you cast a polymorph spell that changes you into a creature of the **animal, dragon, elemental, magical beast, plant, or vermin type**, all of your gear melds into your body. Items that provide constant bonuses and do not need to be activated continue to function while melded in this way (with the exception of armor and shield bonuses, which cease to function). **Items that require activation cannot be used while you maintain that form.** [...]

Comment: This contradicts itself, as the activation for constant-effect items is putting the item on.  *To use a magic item, it must be activated, although sometimes activation simply means putting a ring on your finger.*  Then, *the using items section seems to imply that basically all continually functioning items are use activated in that of the four ways they are not spell completion, spell trigger, or command word items*.  Under use activated *A character has to drink a potion, swing a sword, interpose a shield to deflect a blow in combat...* But you can get the wild enchantment on a shield.

Comment: @ChrisPy The crucial detail I think you're overlooking is that it *doesn't* say “constant effect,” it says “constant **bonus**” and the ability to *spider climb* granted by the Slippers is not any kind of bonus. “Bonus” means a +[number].

Comment: Okay, so in that case, the constant bonus of +4 to acrobatics when making a jump in the case of Boots of Striding and Springing is fine, however, say, in the case of a ring of feather fall, it'll stop working once the Druid is wild shaped as it doesn't provide any numeric bonus.  These are the most popular search result for stuff like this (So you can see where I'm coming from): [Here](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2l333?Druids-and-Wildshape-and-their-Magical-Items) and [Here](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2klac&page=4?Wild-shape-Shields#177)